# node js sync https requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, promise

I have code:

```
`//...
.then(function () {

   var opts = {
        method: 'GET',
        agent: new https.Agent({
          rejectUnauthorized: false
        })
      };
   var url = 'https://***';

    return fetch(url, opts)         //work stopped here
      .then(function(res) {
        console.log(res.status);
        return res.text();
      })
})
.then(function(result){
  //do not get here
})`
```

I want to make a request, the response to pass on. For queries use [this lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

Comment: What is your question?  What is it that you want help with?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have no catch call at the end.

Comment: Solved the problem. Used this library: https://github.com/request/request-promise.